# Extend range from active cells in four directions vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I´ve managed to select a range with content by using this:

`Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select`

Now i want to extend that range in four directions, probably with a Offset function. For example I want the range selection C3:D6 to become B2:E7.

And if possible C3:D6;F3:G6;I3:J6 to become B2:K7 somehow

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible

[image]

```
Sub TestResizeAndMergeAreas()
    Dim r As Range

    Worksheets.Add

    Range("C3:D6,F3:G6,I3:J6").Value = "Test Data"

    Range("A1:Z20").Select

    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Before:", r.Address

        ResizeAndMergeAreas r, -1, 1, -1, 1

        Debug.Print "After:", r.Address
    End If

    r.Select
End Sub

Sub ResizeAndMergeAreas(ByRef Target As Range, x1 As Long, x2 As Long, y1 As Long, y2 As Long)
    Dim rArea As Range

    For Each rArea In Target
        Set Target = Range(Target, rArea)
    Next

    Set Target = Target.Offset(x1, y1).Resize(Target.Rows.Count + x2 + (x1 * -1), Target.Columns.Count + y2 + (y1 * -1))

End Sub
```

Comment: Should this work by itself cause I´ve tried it in my workbook and  in a new one but nothing happens, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When i run this I end up with a new sheet, "Test Data" written in C3:D6;F3G6;I3.J6 and a selection of A1:Z20

Comment: Wow! thank you for your patience, after looking at the code for a while I´m close to understanding it and after a couple tests and edits maybe I´ll do, but the end result of this is exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: I´ve done some test runs with it now and ran into a problem, if one of the areas with content is longer than the others It will not be included unless it´s the last one. If I for example have content in C3:D10;F3:F7;I3:J7 I´ll end up with B2:K8 what I would want it to be is B2:K11 any suggestions ? :)